# Questions about Christianity get down voted

Tags: discussion

I asked a couple of questions that contained references to Christianity. These questions got downvoted for the fact it included certain facts of Christianity or its values and not because it was a bad question.

I can't provide links to this questions because I deleted them in the end.

I still have [one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38895/did-jupiter-enter-into-the-body-of-the-constellation-virgo) available though. The question has nothing to do with Christianity. I only used one reference that happens to be a Catholic one. But the question in itself is about astronomy. They say this isn't a notable claim. Well, the link(claim) is only for the viewers to see what I mean otherwise I wouldn't use it. I would just simply ask "Is Jupiter entering Virgo during this time" or so because some people say that it does. And then I could link sites that show it doesn't...

Comment: @Grasper downvotes in meta do not affect your reputation and merely mean disagreement, so please don't get upset. On the other hand I don't think it's fair to call your behavior as trolling (although we really can't think of how to help you at the moment!)

Comment: A vote on a Meta-question implies that people agree with your proposal, and/or that the question is useful. Here I think you're proposing that questions about Christianity are downvoted ... people disagree with that allegation (as stated in the answers) which may be why the question is downvoted ... another reason for the downvote might be the lack of evidence (lack of hyperlinks) in the question, which makes the question "unclear or not useful" (which, being unclear or not useful, is another good reason for downvoting a question).

Comment: -1, for not being able to provide links or examples, because this fails to be much of a discussion when you've deleted the content that it could've been a discussion about.

Comment: I have downvoted this question for not containing proof for us to assess. You are claiming "good" Christianity questions are downvoted yet not providing the questions.

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub, it is because I don't have an access to downvotes. The question itself can be up-voted but there are many down-votes too. And my suspicion is what I claim as the reasons. Let's say a question can have 35 upvotes and 20 downvotes so the question only has 15 upvotes and you think so "what is the problem?". It's the invisible downvotes given by wrong reasons.

Comment: But downvotes happen everywhere; even to non-Christianity questions. How do you explain that

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub, yes but my point was that for the question about Christianity or containing something from Christianity get downvoted for the reason that it is about the religion and not the actual quality of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question about Jupiter was trivial. That's why it was down voted.

But you're right. This community has a higher number of atheists (and other varieties of non-believers and non-sympathizers) than any other SE site. And they tend to be especially critical of any Christian topic.

I don't find this particularly true of questions, because questions are often asked to make the religion or a group of its followers look foolish. It's quite true for answers. Basically, if the question can elicit an answer that makes Christianity look dumb, it gets up votes, and that's most of them. But if an answer comes along and doesn't make Christianity look dumb, or doesn't make it look dumb enough, it will find less favor or none at all.

Solution: Deal with it. Know your audience. And remember confirmation bias is the most common cognitive bias. You can't win this argument.

Comment: I can think of multiple examples where the pro-Christianity answer won over way more votes than it deserved (in my atheist opinion). It might be that we both notice when it hurts.

Comment: @Sklivvz Maybe, but I'm not Christian.

Answer (score 5):

The accusation - that good questions are being downvoted by the community *because* they are about facts of Christianity - is a serious one, but given that there is a high proportion of atheists in the Skeptics community, a bias isn't beyond imagining. So, with a heavy heart, I went to investigate, wondering what I would see in the comments that would reveal that these were the reasons for the downvotes.

I looked through your deleted questions. There is a fair number of them (23), of which nine have a negative score. Seven have a vote score of -1, one has a vote score of -2 and one has a vote score of -3. Neither of the latter two are about Christianity, and they are dated over two years ago, while you were learning the ropes here.

I concluded that there is no heavy downvoting of your questions about Christianity. *Perhaps you can explain further why you think that this is the case.*

I also looked at the [christianity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity), and it seems to be well voted. I couldn't see a problem there either.

(I see @Sklivvz has already looked at the Jupiter question, so I will stop at this point.)

Comment: It is not just mine questions. I noticed when someone tries to make a point about the Christian values. The question gets downvoted just because it is about Christianity. I understand we can't avoid this but do you think this can disqualify this page as a proper source of something where people are trying to find an objective truth? So what is this page about? Try to verify claims or twisted facts or stoning the ones with "wrong" questions just because they happen to have different facts?

Comment: @Grasper Please back up your claims, or you're likely to be ignored as a troll - which is what that comment and this question appear to be. Both are baseless AFAICT. There are good questions and bad questions on *all* subjects. Religion is no different.

Comment: @Jamiec, I can't back up my claims because these type of questions are suppressed and not available to me anymore. This is just my observation and now maybe you need to investigate if that's the case. And if you think I'm just a troll then I think it's time for me to delete this question which will again prove my point.

Comment: @Grasper I think, until you can back up your assertions, that is a very good idea.

Comment: @Jamiec, ok, if you guys are always right and know the reasons why people downvote because you can read their minds and the burden of proving is on my shoulders then there isn't a reason to have meta site for skeptics because you will always deny someone's observation. You back up your claims that it is otherwise? I can always dismiss your claims the same way you can mine.

Answer (score 2):

I remember I've answered some questions about (aspects of) Christianity, including:

- [Did Pascal write: "Men never do evil so completely and cheerfully as when they do it from religious conviction"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/17776/2703)
- [Did Pope Gregory IX call the Holy Fire a fraud?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/27323/2703)
- [Does the Catholic church accept evolution?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16414/2703)
- [Did Augustine of Hippo warn Christians to beware mathematicians?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/34756/2703)

These questions weren't downvoted.

You may be right (I can't know, since you've given no evidence) that *some* questions about Christianity are downvoted; in particular that some of *your* questions about Christianity are downvoted; it doesn't seem to be true though that *all* questions about Christianity are downvoted ... so logic proposes that if a question is downvoted it's not because it's a question about Christianity.

There may be some reason[s] why your questions about Christianity are downvoted, but if you won't link to those questions, it's impossible for people to suggest how to improve them.

Note that many questions (in general) *are* downvoted on Skeptics. The Skeptics site has a peculiar and strict kind of format for the kinds of questions it expects/allows/upvotes (i.e. "notable claims").

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your questions, including deleted ones, I don't have the impression that questions about Christianity get downvoted particularly harshly. For example in the Jupiter one people express doubt in the comments about how notorious or trivial the claim is, but no one seems to express a dislike for the "Christian" source.

Looking at your historical questions there are at least two Christianity related ones which are highly successful: [Was EU flag's design inspired by the statue of Virgin Mary?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38661/was-eu-flags-design-inspired-by-the-statue-of-virgin-mary) and [Does area of the brain associated with the sense of self "shut down" when praying?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38462/does-area-of-the-brain-associated-with-the-sense-of-self-shut-down-when-prayin).

Am I missing something? Is there anything else we should look at?

Comment: The ones that are successful are because the answers are in opposition to Christianity and I phrased the question that way too.

Comment: The EU flag answer is not in opposition to Christianity. The brain shutting down question has not been phrased in opposition to Christianity. Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: @Oddthinking, from the answer: "Using 13 stars was considered unlucky." How in the world can the superstition be a valid reason to deny 13 stars but promoting religious inspiration is unlikely for 12 stars?

Comment: @Grasper if you can't provide specific examples that need our intervention and we can't find any, there's nothing we can do at the moment. Please keep us informed.