# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Skeptics breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  5         25
Users destroyed                                  30          0
Users deleted                                     2          0
Users contacted                                  12          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           110        816
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                2        269
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          0        272
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0         91
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 0        571
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                0        530
Tags merged                                       1          0
Questions reopened                               60          5
Questions protected                              11         27
Questions migrated                                2          0
Questions flagged⁴                                7        691
Questions closed                                366         88
Question flags handled⁴                         295        403
Posts unlocked                                    1          2
Posts undeleted                                  12         32
Posts locked                                      4         67
Posts deleted⁵                                  537        498
Posts bumped                                      0         23
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               39          0
Comments flagged                                  5      1,031
Comments deleted⁶                             5,545      1,326
Comment flags handled                           846        190
Answers flagged                                  38      1,012
Answer flags handled                            876        174
All comments on a post moved to chat             74          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [Community, user #-1](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: This is the first I've seen this, so if it's new, I want to say thank you for providing it. Where can I get totals? Can I infer some, like "all flags of all types"? What about total answers or questions? Thanks

Comment: Some of us recently in meta thought it would be useful to compare Skeptics moderation to other sites, but we can't do that without totals.

Comment: @fredsbend You can compare each year individually. Also if you were not aware, if you write 2 comments in a row within 2 minutes, you can edit the first one to make it longer rather than writing 2 comments (though I understand that sometimes it makes sense to write 2 separate comments).